# Calculate failure percentage from the given table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have a table that looks like below

```
eventType.    deviceModel.    deviceType
received        S8             Samsung
success.        S8             Samsung
failure         S8             Samsung
.
.
.

      received = indicates that 'A' event was received
      Success =  indicates that 'A' event was processed successfully
      failure = indicates that 'A' event failed to process
```

I want to aggregate this data and calculate the % of failure for the deviceType and deviceModel combination.

Essentially I need first count all the entries with eventType "received" for a particular deviceModel and deviceType.

Then count the all the entries with eventType "success" for same deviceModel and deviceType combination and then calculate % of (total of received - total of success)/total of time * 100.

How can I do this using a SQL query?

I expect the output like

```
 deviceType.     deviceModel.       Failure %
 samsung         S8                  10%
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  It is not obvious how "time" is represented in the data and that seems rather important.

Comment: It seems EventType column is of string data type (perhaps varchar2). It makes sense to have values 'success' and 'failure'. What does 'time' mean though? That doesn't make any sense to me. Do you have THREE different possible types, called 'success', 'failure', and 'time'? What does 'time' mean - and how should it be handled?  In your question you show a computation where only 'time' and 'success' are even mentioned - nothing about 'failure'. What does all that mean?

Comment: I have changed "time" to "received" to avoid the confusion. Yes, I have 3 different eventTypes 'receieved', 'success' and 'failure'. 
received is published to the table when the event is received
success is published to the table when the event was processed successfully and failure is published when the event failed to process.

Comment: so I want to calculate the % of failures based on the number of events "received" and number of events with "success"

Comment: So, an event "fails" if it has a "received" row and no other row? Meaning, it is a "failure" if it has a "failure" row, and it is also a failure if it doesn't - as long as it does **not** have a "success" row? This seems to be the case from what you have written, twice now (in the original post and in the last comment).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select deviceModel, deviceType,
       avg( case when eventType = 'received' then 1.0 else 0 end ) as received_ratio
from t
where eventType in ('received', 'success')
group by deviceModel, deviceType;
```

Or is this the logic?

```
select deviceModel, deviceType,
       sum(case when eventType = 'received' then 1
                when eventType = 'success' then -1
                else 0
           end ) / count(*) as received_ratio
from t
group by deviceModel, deviceType;
```

Neither of these take "failure" into account, but you seem to be asking for one of them.

EDIT:

If you want the ratio of failures, that would be:

```
select deviceModel, deviceType,
       avg( case when eventType = 'failure' then 1.0 else 0 end ) as failure_ratio
from t
group by deviceModel, deviceType;
```

Comment: This seems to take only deviceModel into account. I want to have the statistics per deviceType/deviceModel combination. Also it is not calculating failure % per se. As total number of received - total number of success for a deviceType/deviceModel combination is the % failure for that combination.

Answer (score 0):

that would be:

```
 select devicxeModel , 
   deviceType,
   Count(Case when  eventtype='Received' then 'Rec' end) - Count(Case when  eventtype='success' then 'suc' end)/count(*)*100 as failure 
 from Table1
 group by devicxeModel , deviceType
```